# What is the time complexity of the function T(n)=2T(n/4)+O(1)?(Without masters theorem)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Can anybody please explain the time complexity of T(n)=2T(n/4)+O(1) using recurrence tree? I saw somewhere it says O(n^1/2).

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the equation for some iteration, and use the mathematical induction to prove the observed pattern:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/4) + 1 = 2(2T(n/4^2) + 1) + 1 = 2^2 T(n/4^2) + 2 + 1
```

Hence:

```
T(n) = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 \in O(2^(k+1))
```

What is `k`? from the expansion `4^k = n`. So, `k = 1/2 log(n)`. Thus, `T(n) \in O(2^(1/2 log(n) + 1)) = O(sqrt(n))`. Note that `2^log(n) = n`.